# Google AppEngine with IMAP module installed

Tags: php, google-app-engine, php-imap

We have PHP application we want to move to Google Cloud in AppEngine if possible.

Unfortunately application relies on PHP's IMAP module which is not available  under php (php56 or php72) or custom (container/linux box) environments Google provides.

Do you know a way to make that module (or any other not included by default) available for the PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to add the IMAP module to App Engine. There is a feature request for the IMAP extension to be added to App Engine PHP, however, it hasn't received a lot of attention.

You can find the feature request here https://issuetracker.google.com/35896390